# How can I change an int ID column to Guid with EF migration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EF code-first approach and want to change the `Id` field to `guid` but can't seem to get past below error.

This is my first migration:

```
public partial class CreateDownloadToken : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.DownloadTokens",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                FileId = c.Int(),
                UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                ValidUntil = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Files", t => t.FileId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Users", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.FileId)
            .Index(t => t.UserId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "UserId", "dbo.Users");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "FileId", "dbo.Files");
        DropIndex("dbo.DownloadTokens", new[] { "UserId" });
        DropIndex("dbo.DownloadTokens", new[] { "FileId" });
        DropTable("dbo.DownloadTokens");
    }
}
```

Later I realized that I need my `Id` column to be GUID so I changed my model file:

```
public class DownloadToken
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public int? FileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FileId")]
    public virtual File File { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime ValidUntil { get; set; }
}
```

When running `Add-Migration ChangeDownloadTokenIdToGuid` it generates this file:

```
public partial class ChangeDownloadTokenIdToGuid : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens");
        AlterColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens");
        AlterColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
    }
}
```

Running this file with `Update-Database` causes this error:

```
Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It was caused because it is impossible to convert previous `int` type of `Id` column to `Guid` type(exactly that try to perform `AlterColumn` method). Also, error message suggest you, that new type of `Id` column can be one of type from set: *int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0*, for them, it is possible to perform conversion from `int` type.

**Solution** - simply drop `Id` column and then recreate it with new `Guid` type, change migration that way:

```
public partial class ChangeDownloadTokenIdToGuid : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens");

        DropColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
        AddColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id", c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true));

        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens");

        DropColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
        AddColumn("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));

        AddPrimaryKey("dbo.DownloadTokens", "Id");
    }
}
```

> P.S. Why you use `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` attribute, not
>   `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`?

Comment: The generated migration script was doing AlterColumn, all I had to do was replace it with a Remove and Add. Boss mode thanks @Slava

Answer (score 21):

Even though Slava Utesinov's works, it only works on empty tables or in cases where no other tables are referring to the table you're converting. So this answer will help those ending up on this page with a more complex database setup.

Below is a utility function you can use from your migration class, which should be invoked from the Up/Down functions. The function also handles tables references the table you're trying to convert from Int to Guid. This helper function assumes the column you're converting is called 'Id', but should otherwise be rather generic.

```
public void Convert(bool toGuid, string parent, params string[] children)
    {
        if (toGuid)
        {
            AddColumn($"dbo.{parent}s", "Id2", c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newid()"));
        }
        else
        {
            AddColumn($"dbo.{parent}s", "Id2", c => c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true));
        }
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            DropForeignKey($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id", $"dbo.{parent}s");
            DropIndex($"dbo.{child}s", new[] { $"{parent}_Id" });
            RenameColumn($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id", $"old_{parent}_Id");
            if (toGuid)
            {
                AddColumn($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id", c => c.Guid());
            }
            else
            {
                AddColumn($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id", c => c.Int());
            }
            Sql($"update c set {parent}_Id=p.Id2 from {child}s c inner join {parent}s p on p.Id=c.old_{parent}_Id");
            DropColumn($"dbo.{child}s", $"old_{parent}_Id");
        }
        DropPrimaryKey($"dbo.{parent}s");
        DropColumn($"dbo.{parent}s", "Id");
        RenameColumn($"dbo.{parent}s", "Id2", "Id");
        AddPrimaryKey($"dbo.{parent}s", "Id");
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            CreateIndex($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id");
            AddForeignKey($"dbo.{child}s", $"{parent}_Id", $"dbo.{parent}s", "Id");
        }
    }
```

So in your case your Up/Down functions would be:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        Convert(true,"DownloadToken");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Convert(false, "DownloadToken");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is EF but for anyone stumbling on this with EF Core in 2021 like me, this is what I did to adapt Andreas Willadsen's code:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>("Id2", "{Parent}s", nullable: false);
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey("FK_{Child}s_{Parent}s_{Parent}Id", "{Child}s");
migrationBuilder.DropIndex("IX_{Child}s_{Parent}Id", "{Child}s");

//if FK reference exists in child you can wipe the child table or..... instead of drop + add column below, need to call renamecolumn, then addcolumn, then use Andreas' post with migrationBuilder.SQL() and update to convert old keys to guid, then finally drop column.
migrationBuilder.DropColumn("{Parent}Id", "{Child}s");
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>("{Parent}Id", "{Child}s", nullable: false);
//

migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey("PK_{Parent}s", "{Parent}s");
migrationBuilder.DropColumn("Id", "{Parent}s");
migrationBuilder.RenameColumn("Id2", "{Parent}s", "Id");
migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey("PK_{Parent}s", "{Parent}s", column: "Id");

migrationBuilder.CreateIndex("IX_{Child}s_{Parent}Id", "{Child}s","{Parent}Id");
migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
    name: "FK_{Child}s_{Parent}s_{Parent}Id",
    table: "{Child}s",
    column: "{Parent}Id",
    principalTable: "{Parent}s",
    principalColumn: "Id",
    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
}
```

Replace {Parent} with your parent table name, {Child} with your child table name, and call the same thing in your Down() except swap <Guid> with <int>.
I want to know why ef core hasn't automated this yet in add-migration.

Comment: This is somewhat dangerous. You are dropping (like you said in your code comment) a whole column. Don't you lose the references between the tables? In Andres Willadsen example, you preserve these relations. You adapted his code but with another requirements. This you cannot do on a existing table, on a production server e.g.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used for a full table in a one to many relationship. newid only works for sql server and Azure. The down does not work with this method.

```
public void ConvertIntIdToGuidId (string tableName, MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.AddColumn<Guid>("Id2", $"{tableName}", nullable: true, defaultValue: new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
    migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey($"PK_{tableName}", $"{tableName}");
    migrationBuilder.DropColumn("Id", $"{tableName}");
    migrationBuilder.RenameColumn("Id2", $"{tableName}", "Id");

    migrationBuilder.Sql(
@$"UPDATE {tableName} SET Id = NEWID () ;");

    migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<Guid>(name: "Id",table: $"{tableName}", nullable: false, oldNullable: true);
    migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey($"PK_{tableName}", $"{tableName}", column: "Id");
}
```