# Using a string for an Primary Key Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've seen this reference: [How to use String property as primary key in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32983524/how-to-use-string-property-as-primary-key-in-entity-framework)

Which details essentially the same issue I am having. 
running the update-database command
results in the following error:

'Identity column 'FormId' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.'

I added the attributes just as the above reference stated and ensured that no Identity attribute is associated with that column in the database I am trying to use yet, after making these changes I am still left with the same exact error message.

I'm really scratching my head hear as to what I am missing. I havent been able to surface any other fixes from my searching. Help would greatly be appreciated.

```
public class Form
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string FormId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}

public class UserForm
{
    public string UserFormId { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public Form Form { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @DavidG: i added the specific class I'm working with that is raising the problem

Comment: Do you have any foreign key relationships defined for this key?

Comment: Yeah, I added the class that references the Form class above. Does that class need some data attribute associated as well? UserForm has a foreign key that will reference the FormId of a Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to create two tables which corresponds to your models with string `FormId` and all is working. I suggest that you not create tables first time, but alter `FormId` from previous type(I think it was `int` type) to new `string` type. If it is so, at your migration you can see `AlterColumn` against your `FormId` column, that try to convert `FormId` to new type, but it is impossible, because they are incompatible. Instead `AlterColumn` use `DropColumn` with `AddColumn` combination. Look at very similar(as I assume) [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022901/how-can-i-change-an-int-id-column-to-guid-with-ef-migration/36028703#36028703), where tried to change PK from `int` to `Guid` type.

Comment: This appears to have done it, thanks for the tip and the reference!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding explicit ForeignKey.

Something like:

```
public class UserForm
{
    public string UserFormId { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public string FormId {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("FormId")]
    public Form Form { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That generated a new error: 
The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Form' on type 'WisconsinTrackClubWebsite.Models.UserForm' is not valid. The foreign key name 'FormId' was not found on the dependent type 'WisconsinTrackClubWebsite.Models.UserForm'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.