# how to change auto increment int to guid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**How do I change my data type for my auto-increment int to a GUID?**

I'm attempting to change the data type of my pk defined like so:

```
 [Id]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
```

...to a guid.

In my model, I've simply changed the data type

[image]

I then ran these two commands:

```
add-migration myIntToGuid
update-database
```

After running `update-database`, I got this:

```
PM> Update-Database

Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Applying explicit migrations: [202101272031026_changeIdToGuid].
Applying explicit migration: 202101272031026_changeIdToGuid.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Identity column 'Id' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, unencrypted, and constrained to be nonnullable.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
```

**How do I change my data type for my auto-increment int to a GUID?**

Comment: Why not add the verbose and share the sql?

Comment: Also, what's the underlying db?

Comment: So what does this 202101272031026_changeIdToGuid script look like?

Comment: Have you looked at this thread for a possible answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022901/how-can-i-change-an-int-id-column-to-guid-with-ef-migration

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server as I think you do, you can't  change the identity column to guid.

The identity column must always be one of the supported types.

See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1600/auto-generated-sql-server-keys-with-the-uniqueidentifier-or-identity/

> The most common ways are via the use of the IDENTITY column property or by specifying a uniqueidentifier (GUID) data type along with defaulting with either the NEWID() or NEWSEQUENTIALID() function.

Or being the key word here. As suggested in the comments follow the guidance here: [How can I change an int ID column to Guid with EF migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022901/how-can-i-change-an-int-id-column-to-guid-with-ef-migration)